# What javap -c does to a classfile?

Tags: java, javac, javap

Actually, the question is a bit broader.
I know that javac compiles java file into a bytecode, a class file. So, class file should contain jvm instructions and all that. On the other hand, the only way to see those instructions is to decompile class file with javap -c. But it isn't decompiling, right? Because if it was decompiling, it would produce java file. So, my guess here is that javac compiles java file like 2 times (which isn't actually true, but let's assume that for simplicity), first to jvm instruction, then to bytecode, so javap -c decompiles from bytecode to jvm instructions. Jvm supposed to understand bytecode, thus it can't understand instructions. I'm a bit confused here. Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html Seems to me that the docs provide enough information?

Comment: Its doesn't do anything to the classfile. It reads it and dumps the bytecode as text.

Comment: @PeterLawrey as text.. as in source code or as in assembly language of jvm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javap doesn't *decompile* the bytecode, it *disassembles* it.  To explain the difference, we can switch the terms the other way around: compilation is translating human readable code to bytecode whereas assembly is translating assembly instructions to bytecode.

Comment: Why does JVM need an assembly language at all? I mean, there is no official assembly for JVM, so from that standpoint, no one will ever write programs for JVM in assembly language.

Comment: @gasan: JVM needs an assembly language because it's useful for humans to talk about instructions like `iload` and `ifeq` instead of `0x15` and `0x99`.

Answer (score 3):

`javap` displays human readable form of JVM instructions. JVM instructions are codes for JVM. What `javap` shows is assembler language.

If you want to see the byte code in more readable form use java decompiler, e.g. [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/). There are several UI wrappers for jad including plug-in for Eclipse.